# Thread-safe invocation of event handler. Avoid NullReference

Tags: .net

There are lots of discussions about

`if (SomeEvent != null)
   SomeEvent(this, null);`

potentially yielding NullReference.

That 

`SomeEventHandler temp = SomeEvent;
if (temp != null)
    temp(this, null);`

is a little better, but compiler can optimize `temp` variable and we're back to the problem.

And then solution to this that's supposed to be stable

`SomeEventHandler temp = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref SomeEvent, null, null)
if (temp!=null)
{
   temp(this, e)
}`

I may misunderstand the way event chain is maintained.
Does this mean that when event from inside the chain is unsubscribed, it's placeholder becomes null?!

Let's say SomeEvent = {eventHandler1, eventHandler2, eventHandler3}.
Some thread unscubscribes eventHandler2 from SomeEvent.
Shouldn't `SomeEvent(this, e)` from the first exerpt simply invoke eventHandler1 and than eventHandler3?

Why NullReference?

I can understand that SomeEvent be null when there are NO subscribers exist.
But than solution is doubtful, because if subscriber unsubscribed, than maybe we shouldn't *forcefully* firing it.

I may have missed something on events. Please explain.

And if null can only appear as a result that there are no more handlers left,
than the whole solution is doubtful, if not stupid.
Because why would I want to invoke event handler on an object that unsubscribed from it (and possibly is disposing now and is in unstable state)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why NullReference?

The backing store for an event is a delegate object. Delegates are immutable. Unsubscribing an event calls [MulticastDelegate.RemoveImpl()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,89414467eca8bd75) to create a new object.  Have a look-see at the code, note how it returns null when there no invocations left.  So yes, SomeEvent can become null while you are busy raising the event.  A classic threading race bug.  Keeping a copy prevents the client code from making it null.

> the whole solution is doubtful, if not stupid

Yes.  If you need this code to do what is intended then there is a problem.  With the workaround in place the event subscriber will get the event even though it unsubscribed it a few nanoseconds ago.  Another threading race bug.

What matters a great deal however is who exactly is being stupid.  The code that unsubscribes the event is very often written by somebody else.  Always the case for an event in the framework, not infrequently the case in your own code.  If that client code uses threads and it doesn't lock properly then it is *your* code that crashes.  Not the stupid code.

You don't want that bug report.

The client code gets to deal with the race.  It caused it, it can do something about it.  You can't.